# questions: possible ways of asking what something does

Tags: word-order, questions, inversion, present-simple

> 1. **What does** your program?
> 2. **What does** your program **do**?
> 3. **What** your program **does**?
> 4. **What is it that** your program **does**?
> 5. Your program **does what**?

Can anyone help me understand how these questions differ in meaning and whether they're correct, less/ more informal, and when they can be used? Am I missing another way of asking what something does? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

1. Grammatically incorrect / Incomplete question (needs a verb)
2. Grammatically correct and is the most formal way in the list
3. to 5. are less formal but asking the same thing.

Comment: I am downvoting this because 3 is not correct English.

Comment: I did not state that 3. is correct.